# Pentaho job communication failure

Tags: mysql, pentaho

When running a Pentaho job I am getting the following error:

```
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 - Couldn't get row from result set
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 - Communications link failure
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 - The last packet successfully received from the server was 0 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,580,751 milliseconds ago.
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2398)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2368)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow(TableInput.java:145)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 - Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 - The last packet successfully received from the server was 0 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,580,751 milliseconds ago.
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3090)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3520)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:935)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1433)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.nextRecord(RowDataDynamic.java:416)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.next(RowDataDynamic.java:395)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7165)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2386)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        ... 4 more
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 - Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 209 bytes, read 160 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2540)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3046)
2015/03/27 19:15:44 - HistoriePersonenObject.0 -        ... 12 more
2
```

The step is saving data to a MySQL table. At the same time a lot of other tables are read from the same MySQL database. What might be causing this error?

Comment: Is MySQL installed in a different server? Are you sure network connection is ok? Do a continuous ping ( ping 111.111.111.111 -t) and run your transformation and check.

Comment: I found this post: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MySQL and I am trying the settings now.

Comment: Nice If it works post it as an answer so that others will also be benefited.

Comment: Sorry. Not working. I'll continue to search. Networkconnection is okay btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I needed to activate connection pooling on my database connection.

Go to your database connection configuration in spoon. Select pooling on the left side and check the `Enable Connection Pooling` checkbox.